# "auto-complete" normal mode command?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, help-system

Once I press `g` (or anything that enters operator pending mode), is there a way to see what keys could follow (e.g. gf, ga etc)?

Alternatively, is there a way to search builtin + mapped keys by regex? I've seen `redir | map`-based solutions, but that ignores builtins.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve got a [plugin that does this for maps](https://github.com/benknoble/popsikey) but only for mappings registered through the plugin.